# problem in query order by decending

Tags: php, mysql

i have 29 rows in mytable with datetime(dt). I want to sort it in descending order
when i query the table it give the result starting from 28 (29 not given) and after 28 it starts from 1, 2....27 where 
        (1-27 datetime is 0000-00-00 00:00:00) and 29 has the recent time.

```
$dt1=$_GET['dt'];
$query="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dt DESC";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$table = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$dt2=$table['dt'];
echo $dt2."
";   // if here i echo $table['id'];  the result is here 29 
if(strtotime($dt1) <  strtotime($dt2))
{
while ($table = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    echo $table['id']."<br />";
    echo $table['name']."<br />";

   }
     }
   else
       echo "false";
```

Why the last id is not shown i.e 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read your first line into `$table` on line 3

```
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
```

So when entering your while loop you read the second row into `$table` causing you to miss the first row.

**EDIT :**
You can prevent this by resetting the rowpointer right before you start your while loop like this:

```
mysql_data_seek($query,0);
while(..........
```

Answer (score 0):

you're doing fetch array out of while loop so in while loop you get -1 records from fetch_array.

As I am guessing you're doing the filter by date with GET['dt'] variable.

you can filter records directly in SQL query.

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dt > {$_GET['dt']} ORDER BY dt DESC
```

beware to pass the correct format of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your line `$table = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);`
 and it will work :

```
$dt1=$_GET['dt'];
$query="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dt DESC";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$dt2=$table['dt'];
echo $dt2."
";   // if here i echo $table['id'];  the result is here 29 
if(strtotime($dt1) <  strtotime($dt2))
{
while ($table = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    echo $table['id']."<br />";
    echo $table['name']."<br />";

   }
     }
   else
       echo "false";
```